# Acentos não aparecem c/ PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo um sistema de certificados para um evento e ao ser inseridas palavras com acentos, eles bugam. Estou utilizando Laravel e uma biblioteca chamada Intervention Image para gerar as imagens dos certificados e adicionar textos nos espaços deixados na imagem. Após gerada a imagem, um PDF é criado.

Segue a imagem do certificado:

[image: Certificado]

Como mostrado na figura, os acentos não estão sendo inseridos. 
Abaixo está o código em que os textos são colocados.

```
                    $img = Image::make(public_path().'/imagens/certificado.jpg');
                    //NOME
                    $img->text($usuario->name, 800, 320, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(60);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });

                    //CPF
                    $img->text($usuario->cpf, 310, 383, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(18);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });

                    //TIPO ATIVIDADE

                    $img->text('Organizacão', 640, 383, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Exo-Regular.otf');
                        $font->size(18);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });

                    //NOME ATIVIDADE
                    $img->text('Comissão organizadora', 1060, 383, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/arial.otf');
                        $font->size(18);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });

                    //TIPO
                    $img->text('Organizador(a)', 670, 413, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(19);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });

                    //HORAS
                    $img->text('40', 945, 413, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(19);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });

                    //MINUTOS
                    $img->text('00', 1010, 413, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(19);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#000000');
                    });


                    //AUTENTICIDADE
                    $img->text('A autenticidade desse certificado pode ser verificada pela URL:', 362, 1030, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(19);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#ffffff');
                    });


                    $file = 'www.feiradascidades.canoas.ifrs.edu.br/validar/certificadocomissao'.$usuario->id;
                    //URL
                    $img->text($file, 392, 1050, function($font) {
                        $font->file(public_path().'/font/Asimov.otf');
                        $font->size(19);
                        $font->align('center');
                        $font->color('#ffffff');
                    });

                    $caminho[$key] = public_path().'/imagens/certificadocomissao'.$usuario->id.'.jpg';

                    $img->save(public_path().'/imagens/certificadocomissao'.$usuario->id.'.jpg');`
```

Esse gerador foi feito via localhost em Windows, mas está hospedado num servidor com Linux. Durante o desenvolvimento em Windows, os acentos funcionaram perfeitamente e após a hospedagem não.

Os **header** de todos os arquivos HTML estão com o charset setados para UTF-8 e na classe que monto a imagem (código acima), está sendo utilizado o `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`

Ao executar o seguinte

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
dd(ini_get('default_charset'));
```

tem-se como resultado isso

[image: UTF-8]

De fato o charset está definido para UTF-8, mas as palavras continuam sem acento. Tentei inúmeras coisas para resolver, mas até agora sem sucesso.

**EDIT:**

Observando melhor, os dados chegam em UTF-8, verificado pelo `mb_check_encoding`. Pelo visto, o problema é na hora de salvar a imagem, porque ela já é salva com o problema dos acentos. Creio que o problema seja nessa parte:

```
$img->save(public_path().'/imagens/certificadocomissao'.$usuario->id.'.jpg');
```

Comment: Salve seu arquivo PHP com a codificação UTF-8. O arquivo deve estar salvo com outra codificação, mas está sendo servido como UTF-8. As codificações precisam coincidir.

Comment: Olá, Esses caracteres da imagem estão vindo de uma base de dados correto? Os registros nessa base de dados estão com os devidos ascentos? O encode da database bate com o encode da aplicação (utf8_general_ci)?

Comment: Desculpe @Fabio, converti sua resposta para comentário e talvez tenha sido rápido demais. Mas entendo que mesmo após a edição, continua sendo um pedido de esclarecimento, certo?

Comment: @bfavaretto o arquivo PHP está salvo com a codificação UTF-8.

Comment: @FabioWilliamConceição os registros no banco estão acentuados corretamente. Está em utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar algo como `$img->text(utf8_encode("Organização"), ...)`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, com utf8_enconde fica assim Organizac^£o

Comment: Segundo uma issue do repo desse plugin (https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/182) pode ser um problema com a fonte. Além disso, tente utilizar mb_check_encoding para checar qual a codificação das strings e mb_convert_encoding (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) para converter a codificação e garantir que elas sejam repassadas como UTF-8 ao plugin, use funções de multibyte (mb_) ao invés de utf8_encode/decode.

Comment: @RômuloGabrielRodrigues problema com a fonte creio não ser, porque a mesma apresenta suporte para Português e também foi testada a fonte Arial. Tentei utilizar o mb_convert_encoding, mas o problema persistiu. O que eu acho estranho é que em Windows, no localhost, ocorreu tudo bem. Entretanto, ao hospedar em Linux, aconteceu de os acentos bugarem

Comment: independente do browser?

Comment: @andrepaulo sim. O problema tá ocorrendo na hora de salvar a imagem gerada. Nessa hora que buga. Debuguei todo o código e vem tudo escrito certo e em UTF-8.

Comment: @RafaelBorba o mb_check_encoding retornou UTF-8? Caso sim, abre uma issue no repo do plugin, pode ser que o plugin esteja com algum problema nessa versão.

Comment: @RômuloGabrielRodrigues sim

Comment: @RafaelBorba tentou usar o htmlentities() (acho que e essa a sintaxe) do php?